# Show PR Build status in Bitbucket

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-server

We have our build pipeline set up with **Team City** (version 2017.1.5) and we use on-premise **Bitbucket** server (version 4.8) for our git repository. Our branching model is [`GitHub Flow`](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)

We use [mendhak Team City](https://code.mendhak.com/teamcity-stash/) plugin to report build status to `Bitbucket` server. Additionally, we have created a build in team city to build pull request with branch trigger: `+:refs/(pull-requests/*)/merge`.

However, the  build status for this branch filter is not visible in the Bitbucket the pull request window/page.

If we use the branch filter on the feature branch (eg. `+:refs/heads/(feature/*)`), the build status is shown correctly on the PR. But, we are interested to display PR build status on our Pull Requests.

We found out that there is already an [open issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3196) with Atlassian since 2013 (**yes - almost 5 years**). It looks like it would not be fixed any time soon.

Ask:

Are there any workarounds or Bitbucket plugins (or Team City plugins) available which can solve this issue. We want to avoid adding any additional branch filter/ trigger.

I feel it is fairly common problem and it should have already been solved by many other teams/ individuals. I just not happen to find out right resource/ material.

Any pointers, is highly appreciated.

Comment: Let me pass this to the Bitbucket team.

Comment: Thanks @hackworks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the ref you're using (under `refs/pull-request/*`) is internal only, and not visible in the Bitbucket web UI.

Imagine you have a repo on Bitbucket Server like this:

[image]

Now suppose you create a PR from "branch" to "master".  The refs visible in the Bitbucket Web UI don't change, but a `git clone --mirror` reveals the hidden `refs/pull-request/*` refs that get created behind the scenes:

```
git clone --mirror http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/scm/bb/rebase-example-1.git
cd ./rebase-example-1.git
git log --all --date-order --decorate --graph
```

Result:

[image]

Having Team City or Jenkins or Bamboo or whatever build using `refs/pull-requests/1/merge` (e.g., `01ebefda503c` in this example) does have one major advantage compared to only building `branch`.
 You get to preemptively build the real thing (the merge) before you actually merge.  It's like a sneak peek into the future.

But it has one major disadvantage if you then try to publish build-status using that same ref.  Commit id `01ebefda503c` is not visible in Bitbucket's Web UI, and so the the pull-request build-status integration won't pick up on the successful (or failed) build.

But there's a nifty workaround.  Let Team City (or Jenkins or Bamboo etc) pointlessly push build-status to the preemptive merge, and then use `curl` to fire off a copy of that same build-status to HEAD^2, aka `01ebefda503c^2` aka `e466842138b65`.

(Background: the caret operator '^' grabs the given parent of the specified commit, e.g., ^1 is 1st parent, ^2 is 2nd parent, and if you're working with crazy people, ^3 would be 3rd parent from an octopus merge, and so on.  Personally I have not seen a real octopus merge in the wild in years.  Also recall that vast majority of commits only have a single parent, aka "string-of-pearls" style commits. Only merges have 2 or more parents.)

You can fire off a build-status against HEAD^2 like so:

```
curl --user user:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \
  '{"state":"SUCCESSFUL", "key":"K", "name":"K-9", "url":"http://bit-booster.com/"}' \
  http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/e466842138b658a1b09caa0b1caea065194311ce
```

Then build-status will be visible on the PR.

And checkout my Bitbucket [add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.bit-booster.bb/server/overview).  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely get you. How can I build the HEAD and send the build status to HEAD^2? Also, could you explain how the second parent of the branch can solve my problem?

Comment: I'll rewrite this response tonight or tomorrow to make the problem and proposed solution more clear.  Stay tuned....  :-)

Comment: HI @Davies can you edit your response to make it easy to understand?

Comment: @AnkitVijay - is that any better?

Comment: Hi @Davies, thanks much for your reply. I think I'm able to understand what you mean here. I have not used curl with TeamCity. That's something I would need to explore. I will have a look and get  back to you if I have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Davies, do you mind explaining me where can I write this curl script? Will it be a "Build Step"?

Comment: Should the BitBucket returns 403 "XSRF check failed" error you need to additionally provide "Origin: <BitBucket base URL>" header

Comment: How do you get the commit-id for HEAD^2 in TeamCity prior to making the curl call?

Comment: To get the commit-id for HEAD^2:  `git log -1 --pretty=%H HEAD^2`